# "Ноль" или "нуль"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать "ноль" или "нуль"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это два слова в русском языке равноправны. Правда, в выражении "ноль-ноль", "ноль без палочки", "ноль внимания" употребляется только "ноль".

Comment: [Нуль без палочки](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%ED%F3%EB%FC&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%E1%E5%E7&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=)

Comment: [Нуль внимания](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%ED%F3%EB%FC&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%E2%ED%E8%EC%E0%ED%E8%E5&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=0), правда основная часть примеров до 1950 года (зато есть "нуль внимания и фунт презрения" из " Кондуита и Швамбрании").

Answer (score 1):

Ноль это цифра, а нуль это состояние, оценка.

Answer (score 0):

И ноль, и нуль равноправны. Тоннель - туннель.